# Banno Authorization API - obtaining addtional claims for Admin/Alert API thru auth grant flow

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We have successfully implemented a auth grant flow using the Banno Authorization API OAuth2/OpendId and obtain a valid **access token** and **id token**.

Next, I am trying to use the **Admin API Alerts** method to  sending a simple push notification to a user. This Alerts API requires the **Institution ID** and a **Unique Customer Identifier**.

1. We’ve enabled these claims (institutionID, userID), in our External Application config.
2. I’ve tried adding the **banno** scope parameter which states taht is will *“Resolve all the Banno-specific claims configured for the financial institution/user.”*,

However that new scope parmeter(**banno**) I see in the documentation is removed from the response(which means it's not valid) and no additional payload is included in the ID Token.

My question is this.  Can I get this additional data fields(**userId**, **instituionID**) in the **id token** through any existing **scope** parameters such as **banno**, or must we specifically add a new **claims** parameter to our auth flow for each specific additional claim data field we require such as:

```
 claims=https://api.banno.com/consumer/claim/customer_identifier https://api.banno.com/consumer/claim/institution_id
```

Comment: can you link to the documentation that mentions using the "*banno*" scope? That sounds like it comes from the old, _unversioned_ way of using OAuth + OpenID Connect with the _Consumer API_. We have a guide for [migrating to the v0 endpoints](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/guides/migratingtooidcversion0/) if necessary, but nevertheless the `v0` endpoints don't have a _banno_ scope anymore. (The new scopes have 'banno' in the fully qualified name but there isn't anything that is _just_ 'banno'.)

Comment: This is the documentation that has the banno scope still listed:
https://banno.com/a/help/banno-help/GUID-7DF1835D-39DF-43AD-B1CC-DCFC08CA09E1.html

Comment: I see. I wasn't aware we had that _old, outdated_ information out there. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things to unpack so bear with me.

> Next, I am trying to use the Admin API Alerts method to sending a simple push notification to a user. This Alerts API requires the Institution ID and a Unique Customer Identifier.

There's some confusion there to clear up. The *Admin API's* [Alerts endpoints](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/alerts/details/) use a `userId` which isn't the same as the "unique customer identifier" described in the *Consumer API's* [claims](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/openidconnectoauth/).

The `userId` used by Banno's various endpoints (in either the *Consumer API* or the *Admin API*) are the same as the "subject identifier" or "sub" claim from the *Identity Token*. The `userId` is only meaningful within the context of *Banno* (and isn't something that can be used by other systems since it's not meaningful to them).

In contrast, the `https://api.banno.com/consumer/claim/customer_identifier` restricted claim says that it is the "Unique customer identifier (CIF or Member Number)". That *is* an identifier that is meaningful to other systems such as the core (e.g. for banks it is the CIF and for credit unions it is the Member Number).

If you're interested in getting the consumer user's `userId` and the Institution ID, those are available (via the *Consumer API*'s implementation of the Authentication Framework) as claims in the Identity Token (the former being the `sub` claim and the latter being the `https://api.banno.com/consumer/claim/institution_details` claim.

- You can then use those values to send alerts via the *Admin API* since you'll have everything you need to fill in the `institutionId` and `userId` parameters for the `POST /a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/users/{userId}/alert/send/generic` endpoint.

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  The sub claim is a no-brainer and obviosuly part of the returned ID token.  For the https://api.banno.com/consumer/claim/institution_details claim, I am assuming I cannot get this through the Scope parameters, and must add a claims property to our authorization request?

Comment: Correct, that needs to be requested via the `claims`. We have a JavaScript example in the [Authentication Framework / OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/openidconnectoauth/) page, and have an example in the [Consumer API OpenID Connect Example / server.js](https://github.com/Banno/consumer-api-openid-connect-example/blob/main/server.js) example project.